# How can i enter a Vec<PubKey> in the solana play ground?

Tags: anchor, web3.js, pda, rpc, program

I want to enter a Vec as input But i can't do that i don't know what is wrong !

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally you would pass a JS array of strings that represent valid pubkeys, like:

`["HXia2kfw8codMQTgDRCqMaDmVpY76aJqwzmGLFsFRfsW", "BMAJg8NEpetxXAihDXMXqxpYcU7Pn6g2rLh9uCfJHsvs"]`

And this works fine if you change the type in the instruction from `vector` to `array`. So I tend to think that it not accepting the same for `Vec<Pubkey>` might be a bug in the Solana Playground.

If you're running the [local version of the playground](https://github.com/solana-playground/solana-playground), if you modify [this line](https://github.com/solana-playground/solana-playground/blob/38145be78b803bacf793f076f8e8c40d48aba9a3/client/src/utils/pg/test/test.ts#L195C70-L195C70) to `this.parse(el, innerType as IdlType, idl)` it will accept an array of pubkeys as string as you would normally expect.

Comment: but we must use "Vec<publicKey>" due to security reasons!

Comment: Not suggesting you shouldn't use "Vec<publicKey>". There are a lot of ways you can test the instruction that will work with "Vec<publicKey>"

Comment: yes you are right i am newbie to solana (i was evm developer) i should try an other way thx.